# How to install Mongodb on Apple M1 chip

Tags: mongodb, macos, apple-m1

I'm trying to install Mongodb community server on macbook air with the new M1 chip following the [official mongodb tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/). However im running into this problem.

```
~ ❯❯❯ brew install mongodb-community@4.4                                
Error: Cannot install in Homebrew on ARM processor in Intel default prefix (/usr/local)!
Please create a new installation in /opt/homebrew using one of the
"Alternative Installs" from:
  https://docs.brew.sh/Installation
You can migrate your previously installed formula list with:
  brew bundle dump
```

Any help with installing mongodb on m1 would be very helpful

Comment: Closing as no-repro (see OP's self-answer below).

Comment: You can just follow the mongodb's official installation guideline. Its pretty descriptive 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

Answer (score 41):

Article on how to install mongodb on apple m1 using homebrew

1. Install homebrew from https://brew.sh/
2. Install xcode command line using

   *`xcode-select --install`*
3. Now to install mongodb use

   *`brew tap mongodb/brew`*

   *`brew install mongodb-community@6.0`*
4. To check if mongodb has been installed use

   *`mongo --version`*
5. to start mongoDB as macOS service use

   *`brew services start mongodb-community@6.0`*

   and to stop mongoDB to run as a background service use

   *`brew services stop mongodb-community@6.0`*

   Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:

   *`mongod --config /opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf`*
6. To run mongodb commands, open a new table and run
   *`mongo`*
7. To check your databases run
   *`show dbs`*

Full documentation here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

Comment: Make the terminal settings to use Rosetta.
Select the app(Terminal) in the Finder. Note that the "Terminal app" could be at "Applications/Utilities". Right click on the app(Terminal) and select Get Info. In General, check the Open using Rosetta check-box.

Comment: `mongo --version` seems not working. instead `mongod --version` worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

I was getting the same problem, on the M1 MacBook Pro. I changed the terminal settings to Rosetta and then tried to install the brew.

For this process, tap with double fingers on the terminal and click on Get Info, and in the menu, click on Open using Rosetta.

Now restart the terminal again and try to install the brew again with this link in the terminal.

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

Now your brew is installed, use this to install MongoDB now, it will work smoothly. You can check the documentation for further process, as it won't make more issues: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

Answer (score 5):

You need to enable Rosetta in your terminal,

1. Duplicate your terminal,
2. After clone it called "Rosetta Terminal"
3. Left click  to enable options and select the option Get info
   [image]
4. Enable Rosetta on your terminal by click on "Open using Rosetta"[image]
5. Start Rosetta terminal
6. Install homebrew from https://brew.sh/
7. Install xcode command line using `xcode-select --install`
8. Now to install mongodb use `brew tap mongodb/brew`
9. Then `arch -arm64 brew install mongodb-community@5.0`
10. If a Warning appears you need to update Xcode tools by

```
Warning: A newer Command Line Tools release is available.
Update them from Software Update in System Preferences or run:
  softwareupdate --all --install --force

If that doesn't show you any updates, run:
  sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
  sudo xcode-select --install
```

11. To check if mongodb has been installed use `mongo --version`
12. To start mongoDB as macOS service use `brew services start mongodb-community@5.0`
13. To stop mongoDB to run as a background service use `brew services stop mongodb-community@5.0`

Comment: "Duplicate" is not allowed for apps, apparently

Answer (score 3):

1. go to https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/ and follow all steps but
2. before **`brew services start mongodb-community@5.0`** run **`softwareupdate --install-rosetta`**
3. now run **`brew services start mongodb-community@5.0`**

Comment: This works in 2022.

Comment: Mind the `softwareupdate --install-rosetta` before running `brew services` or `mongod`

Answer (score 1):

This was a problem with brew and fish shell. It works now when installing from bash. Mods can remove this or whatever they like

Comment: Yes, because thats the purpose of Stackoverflow. Delete the question, whenever you get an answer :-D