# Installing mongodb on M1 Apple Chip with cannot tap mongodb/brew: invalid syntax in tap

Tags: mongodb, macos, homebrew

Running the command brew tap mongodb/brew: i ran into the following.
I ran into the following :

Error: Invalid formula: /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/mongodb/homebrew-brew/Formula/mongocli.rb

formulae require at least a URL

Error: Cannot tap mongodb/brew: invalid syntax in tap!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### My Solution :

- Go to Finder > Utilities and right click on Terminal and select "Get Info"
- Find the option "Open using Rosetta" and check it.
- Open new Terminal
  Run

```sh
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

- Run
  `"brew tap mongodb/brew"`

After it completes close the terminal and uncheck "Open using Rosetta".

- open Terminal again and then run `brew install mongodb-community@4.4`.

This did not work for me so i tried this:

- Then run this : `arch -arm64 brew install mongodb-community@4.4`
  And it worked.

I suggest you find the one that works for you.
Thanks to these articles.

- [How to install Mongodb on Apple M1 chip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65357744/how-to-install-mongodb-on-apple-m1-chip)
- [Does the mongocli support a formula URL for Apple M1 chips?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66381265/does-the-mongocli-support-a-formula-url-for-apple-m1-chips)
- https://brew.sh/

Answer (score 2):

Go to Finder > Utilities and right click on Terminal and select "Get Info" Find the option "Open using Rosetta" and check it.

Open new Terminal and run "brew tap mongodb/brew" After it completes close the terminal and uncheck "Open using Rosetta", open Terminal again and then run "brew install mongodb-community@4.4".

Answer (score 0):

Run these two commands in your terminal to add Homebrew to your PATH:
(echo; echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"') >> /Users/<>/.zprofile
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"