# mongodb-community not working on Apple M1

Tags: mongodb, apple-m1

I've installed mongodb-community version 5.0 using brew, following this post's answer for M1 Apple Silicon Macs: [How to install Mongodb on Apple M1 chip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65357744/how-to-install-mongodb-on-apple-m1-chip)

Everything works fine, until the 6th step.

1. After running "mongo" in my terminal, I get the [following errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTybr.png).
2. I searched over stackoverflow and suspected that perhaps the mongodb service is not running, but the command "brew services list" gives the
   [following output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdvNd.png).
3. Running "mongod" gives the [following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3vUd.jpg).
4. Yet, checking "mongo --version" gives a [clear indication of installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXYqH.png).

I have also uninstalled mongodb various times, started afresh with the whole procedure.

---

I'm so frustrated at this point. It would be really helpful if someone could let me know what's wrong in this process/how I could fix it.

PS: This is one of my first posts and I'm sorry if it is not structured well or does not follow a community guideline. I can try to edit the post if any rule is violated.

Thank you.

Comment: Getting "connection refused" means nothing is listening on that port, which would imply that step #5 didn't work properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution worked for me
[Read-only file system when attempting mkdir /data/db on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58034955/read-only-file-system-when-attempting-mkdir-data-db-on-mac)
rom the official docs https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

Install homebrew and run the following commands

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```

then

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
```

then

```
brew install mongodb-community@4.2
```

and

```
brew services start mongodb-community
```

or

```
mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
```

then

```
ps aux | grep -v grep | grep mongod
```

and

```
mongo
```

to verify you can run show dbs in the mongo shell

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this step for reinstalling mongodb, it works for me:

- 1st: run this command (Prerequisites)

```
xcode-select --install
\\note: Homebrew requires the Xcode commandline tools
```

- 2nd: install Homebrew for M1 chip (Prerequisites)
- 3rd: run this command to get Homebrew formula that work with mongodb

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
```

- 4th: run this command to get mongodb version 5

```
brew install mongodb-community@5.0
```

- 5th: run this command to run mongodb in the background

```
brew services start mongodb-community@5.0
// I notice that if I don't run this command I cannot connect to the server and receive the same error message like you
```

- 6th: just run mongo and enjoy. I hope it works.